# How to use Xamarin Forms PCL code from a Background Task in WP8?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to use the PCL code to access a SQLite database from a periodic background task in windows-phone-8.

However, I get this error: `InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it`

Trying to do a `Forms.Init()` when the agent is invoked like so

```
    protected override void OnInvoke(ScheduledTask task)
    {
        Forms.Init();
```

throws `UnauthorizedAccessException: Invalid cross-thread access.`

Also tried `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { Forms.Init(); });` but that also didn't work.

**What is the proper way of using the common code from the PCL project in a background task?**

**EDIT:**

- I'm calling `Forms.Init()` in the [startup page](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/#Windows_Phone)
- Not doing any UI updates from the background task. The exception is thrown when trying to use the `DependencyService` to get the platform-specific connection details: `DependencyService.Get<IDatabaseConection>().GetConnection();`

Comment: You might need to try a DI container that is not dependent on Forms?  I don't know much about WP8 background processing - this may be a bug in Forms?  I do know that you should not need to call Forms.Init() more than once in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the problem by using a different IoC container, as @Jason also suggested. [AutoFac](http://autofac.org/) did the trick for me.

Tried first with `TinyIoC` but got the same errors referenced [here](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC/pull/31):
`Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BindingFlags' could not be found.
Are you missing an assembly reference? (CS0246)`.

Other [IoC containers that should work with Xamarin](http://arteksoftware.com/ioc-containers-with-xamarin/).

**It's still unclear why Xamarin's IoC requires the `Forms.Init()` call**

Comment: How did you manage to install `AutoFac` as it is not compatible with xamarin pcl , which version you are using ?